# Determine measure unit.

Tags: unit-of-measure

Determine a measuring unit of $B$ and $k$ if $T$ is a temperature in Kelvins, $t$ is time in seconds and $L$ is the length in meters. 
$$T(t)=T - (1 - e^{-kt})(1 - B - L^2)$$

Comment: I assume that measuring unit for k is just $s^{-1}$ but I have no idea how to find an answer for B.

Comment: If $L$ is length in meters then $L^2$ is meters squared, but $1$ is dimensionless so this formula literally doesn't add up. Are you sure that's exactly what it said?

Comment: I am sure, but it is probably incorrect.

Comment: An error in the problem statement does appear to be likely.